# Java: How can I recursively call my method with an original param in the recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, queue

I have a method I made to calculate the capital gain/loss of a stock market program using an ArrayQueue implementation.

But I need to call this method recursively in order to calculate the capital correctly.

Example: 
I have 3 purchase transactions (objects) in the queue. 100 shares for $10 each, 150 shares for $20 each, and 50 shares for $30 each. But now I want to sell only 275 shares and at a price of $25 each.

Here is my method to calculate the capital:

```
public static int calculateCapital(Transaction sale, 
                                   Transaction purchase, ArrayQueue q) {

    int sharesRemaining = 0;
    int capital = 0;

    //if shares to be sold is less that the shares in the next transaction
    if (sale.getShares() < purchase.getShares()) {

        //calculate the capital
        capital = capital + (sale.getShares()*sale.getPrice())-
                            (sale.getShares()*purchase.getPrice());

        // return the remaining shares to the queue
        purchase.setShares(purchase.getShares()-sale.getShares()); 
        q.enqueue(purchase);

    //if shares to be sold are more than the shares in the next transaction
    } else if (sale.getShares() > purchase.getShares()) {

       //calculate the capital
       capital = capital + (sale.getShares()*sale.getPrice())-
                           (sale.getShares()*purchase.getPrice());

       //store the remaining share count needed to be sold
       sharesRemaining = sale.getShares() - purchase.getShares();

       sale.setShares(sharesRemaining);

       Transaction nextPurchase = (Transaction)q.dequeue();

       while (sharesRemaining > 0) {
          // RECURSIVELY CALL CALCULATECAPITAL METHOD
          calculateCapital(sale, nextPurchase, q);
       }         

    //if shares to be sold are equal to the shares in the next transaction              
    } else if (sale.getShares() == purchase.getShares()) {

       //calculate the capital
       capital = capital + (sale.getShares()*sale.getPrice())-
                           (sale.getShares()*purchase.getPrice());

    }

    return capital;

}
```

I am getting an error when I run the client test program saying that the Queue is empty when it goes to dequeue the next transaction and I think it is because I am not passing the same Queue into the recursive call but an empty one.

Is there a way to pass the same Queue entered into the original method call into the recursive one? Like with `calculateCapital(sale, nextPurchase, this.q);`?

Comment: `q` *is* the original object passed into your method, so using `q` will pass that same object on to whatever method you want, even if it is a recursive call to the same method.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace of your exception? It is really hard to pinpoint the problem in this amount of code.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: if a method calls itself, _each_ invocation of the method will have a separate copy of the local variables.  So if we call `calculateCapital[1]` the first one that's called, and `calculateCapital[2]` the one where it calls itself, they will not share `sharesRemaining`.  If `calculateCapital[2]` changes its own copy of `sharesRemaining`, that will not affect the local variable in `calculateCapital[1]`.  Therefore, the `while` loop can never terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code - the biggest is that you do not want to use a `while` loop to make a recursive method call. If `sharesRemaining` is 10, for example it will remain as such forever (it is a local variable). What you want to do is use an `if` statement and add the result of the method call. You are also making a call to `q.dequeue();` before checking to see if there are any additional `sharesRemaining`, this should be moved inside the `if` statement.

```
   // more code above this, but...

   /* you do not want to use sale.getShares() as this is a decrementing value 
      as the method is called recursively. you want to know the purchase price
      for the number of shares in this transaction using the purchase price and
      sale price. use a double instead of int to calculate cents */
   double salePrice = purchase.getShares() * sale.getPrice();
   double purchasePrice = purchase.getShares() * purchase.getPrice();

   // calculate the capital, only for this transaction
   double capital = salePrice - purchasePrice;

   // store the remaining share count needed to be sold, this is passed into the method
   // and why it should not be used to calculate the capital
   sale.setShares(sale.getShares() - purchase.getShares());

   // If we have more shares, call the method to process the next one.
   if (sale.getShares() > 0) {
      // Get the next transaction
      Transaction nextPurchase = (Transaction)q.dequeue();

      // Add this value to the value of the "next" transaction, recursively
      capital += calculateCapital(sale, nextPurchase, q);
   }
```